# How do I guarantee that everything inside a onsubmit callback will get run before the form is submitted?

Tags: javascript, analytics, jquery-events, onsubmit, optimizely

I have [Optimizely](https://www.optimizely.com/) on a page that also has a Google Form on it, and I want to track events when the form is submitted. This is roughly the code I have now:

```
  window.optimizely = window.optimizely || [];
  $('#ss-form').on('submit', function() {
    window.optimizely.push(['trackEvent', 'submit']);
  });
```

The problem is that it's severely under-reporting the number of submits that actually happen.

The only explanation I could come up with (and so did Optimizely support) is that most of the time the form is getting submitted and the next page is getting loaded **before** the optimizely tracking code finishes running. It has to make a request to Optimizely before the form POST request is made to Google, so its running time is probably non-negligible.

---

How do I ensure that the whole callback **will definitely** run to completion before the form is submitted?

P.S.: Optimizely support mentioned this might also have something to do with the fact that the page is hosted on one domain and submits to a different one (Google's), but I'm not sure if that has anything to do with this.

Comment: `optimizely` needs to emit an event when it's done. It's hard to impossible otherwise.

Comment: @JanDvorak is the hypothesis correct though? Is that the cause of underreporting? Why would the browser allow the form submission/page load to interrupt an `onsubmit` callback? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of having this specific event altogether? It's kind of useless if you can't trust it to perform its work right?

Comment: You could track the event from the other page (where the form is submitted to)

Comment: The other page is the Google Form's "thank you" page, and I don't have control over it (can't add js to it).

Comment: The only problem is that when the page is unloaded, all pending XHRs are aborted. The script itself does finish, but the ajax doesn't have the time to leave.

Comment: You could submit to a log&redirect page.

Comment: Hm... interesting. Any way I can force it to wait for all pending XHRs to go through first?

Comment: You could prevent the submit, wait a few milliseconds, then trigger the submit manually.

Comment: Is there a way to tell Optimizely to make synchronous calls?

Comment: That would still be non-deterministic, right? It would probably catch more submits, but still might miss some that take longer than whatever timeout I set?

Comment: I _think_ there's only one AJAX to leave. In that case, waiting should be reliable (once it starts, timeout callbacks will have to wait, and it should start immediately).

Comment: I vote for log&redirect, or ditching Optimizely completely.

Comment: or a third option, send your own _synchronous_ AJAX manually to do the logging.

Comment: About the waiting option, would that be just calling a `setTimeout(fn, 0)` after the `optimizely.push()` code, inside the `onsubmit` callback code?

Comment: In jQuery, synchronous AJAX is as easy as setting the `async` option to false: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: `setTimeout(fn, 0)` _should_ work. No promises, though.

Comment: Re: setting `async` to false, I would have to find the xhr call in their minified code and monkeypatch it though, right? Will try `setTimeout` and report back.

Comment: You should be able to call their logging calls from your own server page to which you could submit manually through your own `$.ajax({async:false, ...` call

Comment: also note if you set the timeout to anything shorter than 4ms, the browser will wait for 4ms anyways: http://jsperf.com/smallest-timeout

Comment: Or you could find what optimizely actually sends, and replicate the behavior with synchronous ajax.

Comment: What about setting a note in `localStorage` or a cookie that you should submit a tracking event?

Comment: Re: the server page, I don't have a server, that's what I was trying to avoid. I'm just serving a static HTML and capturing results on a Google Spreadsheet. And re: cookie and localStorage, I can't add JS to the form submission confirmation page, so I wouldn't be able to look into the stored note to submit the event afterwards. The general question bugs me though: how can it be that the API offers a callback on an event and then doesn't guarantee it will be run?

Comment: The callback (`submit`) does always run, and always finishes. AJAX also always calls its callback. The only case when a callback is not called is when the page unloads - and this has to happen - the browser _has_ to kill the javascript at some point. Even then, the 'unload' event is guaranteed to be called and finish.